# Twilio Video not publishing on slower network

Tags: google-chrome, safari, twilio, webrtc, twilio-video

I am building a SPA using Reactjs. It is a one on one video calling web app.

It is designed for a person to call another person from a mobile browsers to laptop browsers or to another native app on mobile devices.

The calling logic in the app is working fine... when both my computer and phone are on wifi. However, when I swap my phone's network to cellular... there seems to be no transmission.

Everything else works the same. When I call, push notification makes the browser ring, I answer, the twilio video handshake happens, and the notifications I get in the console show that both clients have "connected" to the room. Both my mobile and the web browsers also show a local video stream - waiting for the other's track. State is maintained as usual. Call time is being tracked etc. But no sound or video stream is being transmitted. But, when I hang up, the logic to handle the hanging up works fine... as if there had been an active call.

When I swap back to wifi, everything works perfectly well, no hiccups.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might happen? I don't have any code to share, because everything is working fine... over wifi. Is there a governor on the core webrtc standard? Or on Twilio Video? Is there a way to change that or throttle the quality to get a connection? (Instead of having nothing for example I would prioritize the respective audio tracks)

Answer (score 1):

Twilio support helped me out and I am posting what they found for anyone who runs up against this same issue.

The problem is with T-Mobile. There was a bug with the network.

See here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=181009

Apparently the issue has been fixed, and will but pushed through, hopefully soon.